# IP 66 rated electronic enclosure

Tags: power-supply, pcb, usb, ethernet

I am a mechanical engineer and I am developing a enclosure for one of the electrical setup. It has usb, ethernet and power supply ports. I am unaware how IP rated USB or any other USB port make sure that there is no water ingress inside the port.   Any suggestion would be great on how this can be achieved.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to not use a standard USB connector. Look for IP66+ rated USB connectors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Hearth. Appreciate it. Is there any way we could use the standard USB connector for these enclosures (IP 66 rated). Or looking out for IP rated connectors are the best options.

Comment: The IP66 probably relates to the housing internal with the connector installed. You'd still have ambient conditions at the connection point. This can be overcome with a removable cover. You could also make the mated connector IP66. O rings are probably a good starting point.

Comment: A look at the images on @Enrico's links makes it clear how the rating is achieved/

Comment: Thank you @RussellMcMahon, so the interior part of the USB is not waterproof? and only the housing is Rated.

Comment: @Rohan  Waterproof connectors are IP6x rated when either the two parts are joined OR a cover is fitted - but probably not otherwise. See pictures on the links that Enrico provides. eg [here](https://www.bulgin.com/products/pub/media/bulgin/data/Standard_ethernet.pdf) on page 71 (actually 4th page of this sub-catalog) there are 3 types of sealing caps with stated purpose of "Sealing caps to maintain IP68 rating when connectors are not in use" ie waterproofness from exterior to interior MAY NOT be (and probably isn't) maintained with the cover off. Connector interior will be wet without cover.

Comment: Thank you @RussellMcMahon. That clears my doubt. Thanks for your time. Can the same procedure be applied for other components like Ethernet connector , GPIO connector etc. Because I did find a similar method for the ethernet connector.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary USB and Ethernet connectors are not IP66 rated.

There are many IP67 and IP68 USB and Ethernet connectors around but I couldn't find one IP66 rated.

---

Reliable manufacturers of IP66/IP67/IP68 rated USB and Etehernet connectors are, among many others: Molex, TE, Bulgin, Amphenol

Molex:
https://www.molex.com/molex/products/family/industrial_usb_type_a_and_b_plugs_and_receptacles

TE:
https://www.te.com/global-en/products/connectors/intersection/industrial-usb-connectors.html?tab=pgp-story

Bulgin:
https://www.bulgin.com/products/pub/media/bulgin/data/Standard_ethernet.pdf

Amphenol:
http://amphenolltw.com/flipbook/AmphenolLTW/ALTW%20catalogue.pdf

---

You can buy them at your local distributor or at Digikey.com or Mouser.com

Comment: Thnaks alot Enrico. Appreciate your time, but any suggestion on how they achieve it, so that if possible, could give it a try.